# Convert signed binary number into integer in Python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

1. I found out that in python, if you use `bin`:

   ```
   >>> bin(4)
   '0b100'  
   >>> bin(-4)
   '-0b100'
   ```
2. but if you try this:

   ```
   -4 >> 8 => -1
   ```

in fact, when right shift more than 3 bits, the answer is always `-1`. I know this is implementation stuff, but I came across this problem:

In the following array, find out the number which appears only once, while others appears always three times

```
[-2,-2,1,1,-3,1,-3,-3,-4,-2]
```

This is the code

```
class Solution(object):
    def singleNumber(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        if nums == None:
            return None
        ans = 0
        for i in range(32):
            numOfI = 0
            for num in nums:
                if (( num >> i) & 1) == 1 :
                    numOfI += 1
                    numOfI %=3
            print i,numOfI
            if numOfI != 0:
                ans = ans + (numOfI << i)
        return ans
```

the answer should be `-4`, but instead I get `11111111111111111111111111111100`; how can I convert it into -4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bit manipulation on Python are easily done with [int.from_bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes) and [int.to_bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes).

On the other hand, solving the "find the value appearing `x` times" is easily solved using the `Counter` class:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> values = [-2,-2,1,1,-3,1,-3,-3,-4,-2]
>>> [value for value, count in Counter(values).items() if count == 1]
[-4]
```

Using `from_bytes` and `to_bytes` is clear and readable, so you don't want to try to do the conversion yourself.

Using `Counter` is also more readable than your cryptic implementation, yet my one-liner may not be the most readable imaginable version, it's still a single line and far more readeable.